# volume jumps to 100% when inserting or removing headphones

Tags: sound, thinkpad, volume-control

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T530.  When I insert my headphones, the volume jumps to 100%, even if it was set lower before I inserted them (and also was lower the last time I used the headphones).  If I then lower the volume and remove the headphones, the volume jumps to 100% again.

The only exception is that if the volume is muted, it stays muted when I insert or remove the headphones.

Any suggestions for what might be causing this?

lspci shows this audio device:
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

Comment: Try booting up a 12.04 livecd. Does this happen when using the livecd as well?

Answer (score -1):

Try controlling the volume using `alsamixer`.